# Use urlrewrite to rewrite all requests to root

Tags: iis, web-config, url-rewriting

I want to use `web.config` and IIS's urlrewrite to rewrite all requests to a certain directory to the root, for example:

From:

```
mydomain.com/directory/test.php
```

To:

```
mydomain.com/test.php
```

and

From:

```
mydomain.com/directory/test/test.php
```

To:

```
mydomain.com/test/test.php
```

All parameters, etc should be passed as well. Any idea how to do this using `web.config`?

Answer (score 0):

I had a requirement for this a while back and found this:

> [Using Url rewrite to "delete" a folder](http://forums.iis.net/t/1173216.aspx)

There's a small error in the rule which was corrected later by the poster. Here's a copy with the correction should the link dry up (I also made it a bit more generic for your requirements):

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>   
    <rule name="RemoveDirectory" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^directory$|^directory/(.*)$" />
      <conditions>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="RewriteToFile">
      <match url="^(?!directory/)(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="directory/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Just search and replace `directory` with your *directory* name.

Comment: I copied this to my web.config and changed the directory names, but it doesn't seem to be making any difference - I've fiddled with it for about an hour, but can't find out why.

Comment: @marathon - can you paste in what you have as an update to your question?